# Android GCM without GooglePlus

Tags: android, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to use GCM (in the new API) for clients that don't have the GPlus APK installed?

I'm not liking the Google dialog approach:

```
GooglePlusUtil.getErrorDialog(gPlusErrorCode, activity, Constants.WAIT_FOR_RESULT_CODE).show();
```

1. It doesn't return to my app immediately after install. It rather directs the users to use GPlus ('open')...
2. It's friction (and maybe even serious friction). I don't want this affecting my conversion rate.

Also: Is there a mature XMPP alternative to GPlus for Android?

10x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use GCM (in the new API) for clients that don't have the GPlus APK installed?

Yes.

> I'm not liking the Google dialog approach:

Since that code has nothing to do with GCM, I fail to see the problem.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html points to http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html which (towards the end) states you need to call  isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() and if the result is other than 'success', call the line I quoted above, in my original inquiry. Is this deduction wrong? e.g - can I use google_play_services-lib without the G+ APK installed, for GCM ? That would be great. (I have no way of uninstalling G+ on my device, so testing is a problem)

Comment: @JRun: "call the line I quoted above" -- no, it does not. It advises you to [call `getErrorDialog()` on `GooglePlayServicesUtil`](http://goo.gl/RfmXI). "can I use google_play_services-lib without the G+ APK installed, for GCM ?" -- yes. Clients need the Play Services Framework installed, which is usually already there on Android 3.0+ devices.